# Router navigation in other page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have appcomponent, here I have added all the routes. In the next page I have few links. each links will route to same router outlet. How can I navigate on click of  tag.

Tried with [routerLink]="['PersonInvolved']". But getting error like "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known native property". Since router and router outlet is defined in first component. And I am linking the router from step1 component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I am currently having the same issue. I have found a workaround until the issue is resolved. But I notice that my dependency is on `router 3.0.0-beta2`, so it might be worth upgrading to latest later. I am under a time constraint so here is what I did.

In your ts file for your component where you want the links use dependency injection to get a `router` object.

```
//Something like this.
constructor(private router: Router){
}
```

Then create a function to do the navigation:

```
navigateSomewhere(){
   this.router.navigate(['yourPage']);
}
```

Then on your `<a>` tag do this `<a (click)="navigateSomewhere()">Click</a>`

Comment: Yeah its beta version problem I guess. Your idea is good.. Thank you